# SAPUI5 MVC App from Single MVC Example

Tags: sapui5

can any one help me converting the below example in mvc? it should have 2 js or xml views and 2 controllers:
http://jsbin.com/openui5-mobile-list-databinding/2/edit?html,output

tnx, sapsm

Comment: can you try something & ask for a question instead of posting someone else snippet & asking for a change!

Comment: well, i've tried couple of ways.. but nothing seems to be working. me on 1.20.9 version. anyways here is wt i had and not working in controller:  
1# app.addPage(sap.ui.jsview("goToPage2","ui5jsbin4js.jview2"));
2# app.to("goToPage2");
3# var bus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
  bus.publish("nav", "to", {id : "ui5jsbin4js.jview2"});

Answer (score -1, accepted):

app.to worked for me in another version.. but i dont say its due to version conflict. some reason.. which i coudn't figure it out. anyways closing as its completed long back.